# Eliminate render blocking css

Tags: html, optimization, http-headers, browser-cache

My CSS files are causing my page to render slowly, which is why I moved them to the footer. This, however creates a UX problem in that when a page loads, it's initially completely unstyled.

I've thought of two solutions to this problem and was wondering which is the best:

- Move the CSS declarations for the navigation bar and page titles to a new CSS file which will be placed in the header. Although this will be a relatively small file, it has the downside of creating another HTTP request
- Inline the CSS for the navigation and page titles in the header itself. Whilst this wouldn't create another HTTP request and would solve the problem, the CSS wouldn't be cached like it would if I put it in an external file.

What is the best solution to this problem? And are there good practice guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the solution to this problem is to embed critical sections (or all) of your css directly into file like (index.html), because if you have more files, that's a new request for each of them and hence more time it takes to load the page :)

Comment: But then the browser would have to download the inlined css on every new page wouldn't it? Are you saying that even though this would add to the overall page size, the difference is insignificant?

Comment: Difference is significant because you make less request :) You rearly have css that is greater then 1MB :) so yeah, search engines are more complaining about number of requests (every link tag is another request to make ) then the size of downloaded css :)

Comment: @AdamScott have you done it, are results better ? :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, the best option is the second one.

[As described here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)

Answer (score 0):

Good practice guidelines are:

- Write as minimum css as possible, avoid writing unnecessary css properties.
- Always try to make a single css file for all styles unless it is necessary to use multiple css files. Even so, do not create more than 3 css file.
- Use CDN link to include frameworks, toolkits.
- Avoid writing inline css styles, use external css file.
- Use html tags properly. html5 introduced some new tags like header, main, aside, nav, footer. Use these tags properly. It gives a clear structure. So it is not necessary to create div class for these tags manually.

My question is that how do you know that your css files are causing your page to render slowly? Are you using any javascript/jQuery plugins?